# SQL Query - Select with a total column

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query that returns rows for current and non-current items.
The current items have no value
The non-current items do have a value

I need my query to return all the current values AND the total value of the non-current items:

Sample:

```
Name   Status       Value
KB     Current      0
KB     Non-Current  5
KB     Current      0
KB     Non-Current  5
KB     Non-Current  5
KB     Current      0
KB     Current      0
KB     Current      0
AN     Non-Current  5
AN     Current      0
AN     Non-Current  5
AN     Current      0
AN     Current      0
```

I would need:

```
Name   Status       Value  TotalValue
KB     Current      0      15
KB     Current      0      15
KB     Current      0      15
KB     Current      0      15
KB     Current      0      15
AN     Current      0      10
AN     Current      0      10
AN     Current      0      10
```

I've tried

```
SELECT Name,Status,Value,(SELECT SUM(Value)
FROM Table
```

but obviously this totals all the values rather than per name, if I try to `GROUP BY Name` then I get the error this returns more than 1 value.

Comment: If current items have no value, then why, according to your example, do they have a value of 0, and why is the sum of all non-current items 15 or 10? Are you grouping by name, by chance?

Comment: by no value I meant 0. 15 for KB as that's the total for that name, 10 for AN, so yes grouping by Name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this totals all the values rather than per name, if I try to GROUP BY Name

You can use `SUM` with [`OVER` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx):

```
SELECT Name, Status, Value,
       SumPerName = SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME)
FROM Table
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/55cf2/1/0)</kbd>

(your sample data is bad since all names are same)

If you actually want to partition by `Status`(which makes your sample data better) you just have to replace `PARTITION BY NAME` with `PARTITION BY Status`.

If you only want records with `Status='Current'` you just have to apply the `WHERE`:

```
SELECT Name, Status, Value,
       SumPerName = SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME)
FROM Table
WHERE Status = 'Current'
```

**Edit**: use a CTE and apply the `WHERE` in the outer query:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT Name, Status, Value,
         SumPerName = SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME),
         Total = (SELECT SUM(Value) FROM Table1)
  FROM Table1
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE Status = 'Current'
```

new <kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b9690/3/0)</kbd> (with sample data that contains two different names)

Comment: How do I only return the Current items though, with the sum of all the values.

Comment: @user3219693: apply the `WHERE`. I've edited my answer. If you also want to include the total sum you have to use `TotalSum=(SELECT SUM(Value) FROM Table)`

Comment: but this falls over when more than 1 name

Comment: @user3219693: you've lost me there. What means _falls over_ exactly?

Comment: i tried this SELECT Name, Status, Value,
       SumPerName = (SELECT SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME) FROM Table1)
FROM Table1
where status='current' and it wont work due to subquery returning more than 1 value

Comment: @user3219693: why haven't you used my query, i've also added a demo which shows that it works. You don't need a sub-query with the `OVER`-clause. Here's again a link to the demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/55cf2/8/0

Comment: Your sql fiddle works when there is only 1 name, but not when there are more. your second example only returns current items and doesnt include the total value for all.

Comment: @user3219693: now i understand. You can use a CTE (similar to a subquery),edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

TSQL offers *window functions* for that:

```
SELECT
    Name
    , Status
    , Value
    , SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY Status) AS SumByStatus
    , SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) AS SumByNAme
    , SUM(Value) OVER () AS SumOverAllReturnedRows
FROM T
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189461.aspx)

I think you need to partition by `Status`. Your example is a bit confusing because `Name` is the same everywhere and the Value is 0 for all `Status=Current` values anyway.

Comment: @Luv what do you mean specificly? I tried it on SQL Fiddle, all the window functions work well there on 2008. Think I've also used such functions a while ago still on 2008.

Comment: @Luv - SQL Server 2008 allows for windowed aggregates. 2012 added features that then meant that ORDER BY also could be used

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.[Name], t1.[Status], t1.[Value], t2.TotalValue
from Table1 t1
left join (select t.[Name],isnull(sum(t.[Value]),0) as TotalValue 
            from Table1 t
            where t.[Status]='Non-Current'
            group by [Name]
            )t2 on t1.Name=t2.Name
where t1.[Status]='Current'
```

**[SQl Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/756fc/1)**